# how to submit update to app store?

Tags: xcode, app-store

I have an app in app store (version 1.0.0), I need to update it to v1.0.1.
Itune Connect status has changed to waiting for upload

in infoplist
I change the Bundle Version to 1.0.1 in xcode
shortversion bundle version also to 1.0.1

What do i do next?

Comment: "I can't archive it" isn't much to go on. Why can't you archive it? Do you get an error? What is it?

Comment: i submit my app through Archive tab under organizer in xcode. So I was thinking doing the same for update

Comment: the archive button is gray, so I cant click it at all

Comment: Did you use the right scheme? Did you chose the iOS device as target device?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your device is set to an actual device, and not Simulator, only then will the Archive option be enabled for you. Note that it does not matter if you have an actual device plugged in at all during this process.

[image]